# jQuery UI autocomplete submit onclick result

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've been trying to figure out how to submit the form when the person selects the result from choices of the autocomplete. It needs to work with a mouse click or enter button. I see examples out there but always in pieces. No one shows the entire function.

I have this code below but I get errors saying result is not a function. I don't know how to combine this to do what I would like. Any help is appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  

jQuery("#vsearch").autocomplete("ajax/search.php",
    {
    minLength: 2
}
);
jQuery("#vsearch").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
      jQuery('#vsearch').value( formatted );
      jQuery('#search').submit();
});
});
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

> **select** - Type:autocompleteselect
>
> Triggered when an item is selected
>   from the menu; ui.item refers to the
>   selected item. The default action of
>   select is to replace the text field's
>   value with the value of the selected
>   item. Canceling this event prevents
>   the value from being updated, but does
>   not prevent the menu from closing.
>
> *Code examples*
>
> Supply a callback function to handle
>   the select event as an init option.
>
> ```
> $( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
>    select: function(event, ui) { ... }
> });
> ```
>
> Bind to the select event by type:
>   autocompleteselect.
>
> ```
> $( ".selector" ).bind( "autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) {
>   ...
> });
> ```

So you would use:

**EDIT:** (modified in case user does not select anything)

```
$("#vsearch").autocomplete({
    source: "ajax/search.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.item){
            $('#vsearch').val(ui.item.value);
        }
        $('#search').submit();
    }
});
```

If I am sure of what you are wanting to do.

Comment: BTW, it you dont make a choice you can't submit whats in the input anyway around that?

Comment: Thanks, hmm it seems it still won't submit by hitting enter when using the select option. I dont think its your code. It might be autocomplete because even without the select option you have to choose something or it won't submit using enter. Because what if the choices arent what you want? Weird, if you have any other suggestions that'd be cool. Thx again.

Comment: I see what its doing. If it doesn't eventually match what you are looking for and doesn't give you any choices, it will submit hitting enter, but as long as there are choice it will only submit using enter when you select an item. If that's how it works I guess that how it works. Thanks for getting me that far.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of service. ;)

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, replace `$('#vsearch').value(ui.item.value);` with `$('#vsearch').val(ui.item.value);` :-)

Comment: @dmnkhhn Editing this late, but I just updated to include that fix.

Comment: thanks so much, for this. it really help me solve my problem related to this. a thousand thanks from me :D

Answer (score 28):

Actually, you don't need to target the for element and form by ID... since that information is already passed to the select function via the Event object. It's better to get the form this way because you may have multiple forms on a page that you want to apply autocomplete to. Or you may want autocomplete on multiple elements.

Also, the syntax in the other answer is wrong. JQuery uses .val() not .value() to set an input's value.

**Here's a corrected example:**

```
$("#vsearch").autocomplete({
    source: "ajax/search.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        //assign value back to the form element
        if(ui.item){
            $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
        }
        //submit the form
        $(event.target.form).submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for using the reference of the object rather than a specific selector (eg. "#vsearch").

Comment: definitely, the way to go this.

Comment: this should be the selected answer